# How to add thumbnails to Wordpress recent posts widget?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I have underscores theme and there is a widget "Recent Posts". I need to show posts thumbnails with every post on this widget. I have enebled thumbnails in functions.php and uploaded them to every post. What i have to do to show these thumbnails in recent posts widget?

In functions.php i have the code

```
/**
 * Register widget area.
 *
 * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar
 */
function mytheme_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', 'fashiony' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'mytheme_widgets_init' );
```

I really have no idea where i have to include `get_the_post_thumbnail();` to do what i want.

Comment: You would include it in what portion of the page you want it to display on, depending on what theme is loading your page parts.  so look for the footer, and header and the main body page are .php files. you would add that snippet `get_the_post_thumbnail();` on the correct part of your template.  Can you add the path of your theme files to the OP above please?

Comment: the widget is displayed on sidebar, so i have to include this function to sidebar.php? And nothing will happen. Sidebar.php contains following code <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>

Comment: OK, this can go two ways here, either 1) there's an easier more proper, by the fact that you may have just technically created a widget, in which case you look in your controls in the admin, under menus, and widgets, to get this stuff added to either a menu, or a page.  have you tried that?  or 2) you have to find your exact theme templates, and add it to your code, making sure its INSIDE the PHP tags of course, where you want it to show up.   Sorry i couldn't be of better help, we will have to wait for better input.. (You can add the answer a useful if it helped you though if possible :-) )